# How to create "random email/password" keyword on order to test "Sign Up" form in Katalon Studio?

Tags: groovy, automation, katalon-studio

Recently started learning Katalon Studio.
Watched a few videos about main functions and how to use. 
In order to test Sign Up form I need to make some kind of random generator custom keyword of email and password in Katalon.

The main problem is - I don't know yet how to write code like this (have no experience). I'd be glad for any help.

This is for an automation web-testing.

I need to create custom keyword before changing this code:

```
WebUI.openBrowser('')

WebUI.navigateToUrl('http://flyshot.phoenixfw.net/login')

WebUI.click(findTestObject('Object Repository/Sign Up/Page_Flyshot  Admin Panel/a_Sign Up'))

WebUI.setText(findTestObject('Object Repository/Sign Up/Page_Flyshot  Admin Panel/input_Sign up with your work email address_sign_upemail'), 
    'transformer@gmail.com')

WebUI.setText(findTestObject('Object Repository/Sign Up/Page_Flyshot  Admin Panel/input_Sign up with your work email address_sign_upcustomertitle'), 
    'ZXC')

WebUI.setEncryptedText(findTestObject('Object Repository/Sign Up/Page_Flyshot  Admin Panel/input_Sign up with your work email address_sign_upplainPasswordfirst'), 
    'MhX+xzZUIsF4+4Abaxd7eg==')

WebUI.setEncryptedText(findTestObject('Object Repository/Sign Up/Page_Flyshot  Admin Panel/input_Sign up with your work email address_sign_upplainPasswordsecond'), 
    'MhX+xzZUIsF4+4Abaxd7eg==')

WebUI.click(findTestObject('Object Repository/Sign Up/Page_Flyshot  Admin Panel/span'))

WebUI.click(findTestObject('Object Repository/Sign Up/Page_Flyshot  Admin Panel/button_Create New Account'))

not_run: WebUI.closeBrowser()
```

I just need to make a couple of automation tests.

Comment: What exactly do you need? Be more specific.

Comment: Manual or assistance how to create keywords i described

Comment: Have you tried following this https://docs.katalon.com/katalon-studio/docs/introduction-to-custom-keywords.html#create-a-package.

Comment: Yes, didnt help(

Answer (score 0):

You can create your code inside the keyword section and call it.

Write this code as a Keyword:

```
import com.kms.katalon.core.annotation.Keyword


class help_keyword_RandomEmail {

    //random mail generator
    @Keyword
    public String getEmail(String suffix,String prefix){
        int randomNo = (int)(Math.random() * 100000);
        return suffix + randomNo + "@" + prefix;
    }
}
```

In your test case :

```
String mail = CustomKeywords.'mubasher.help_keyword_RandomEmail.getEmail'('opps'(suffix is here), 'mailinator.com' (prefix is here))

WebUI.sendKeys(findTestObject('Sign Up/email'), mail)
```

Comment: Still have no idea how to create a keyword for password and insert into the very script.Maybe you can provide with few nice detailed videos or a page?

Comment: Check the updated answer. this is only for password.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to save those and use them (e.g. for signing in, or deleting them afterwards) it's unwise to use new random ones everytime (unless you can't clean up afterwards), u may use Test Data (specify the accounts in an Excel sheet)

If you only need one account, you may just use a GlobalVariable that stores random values from the initialisation for further usage. Check the other answer for that.